# Restore /var owner and group (mysql and apache needed)

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

Huh, I feel kinda dumb right now. 
Just did an

```
chown -R www-data:www-data .*
```

and voilá, /var is all messed up.
Already fixed some to root, but mysql refuses to start.
How can I restore the owner/group to /var/* on a Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS ?
Thanks!

Comment: If nothing better, boot up other ubuntu VM and copy one by one :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Done it already, did't work. also fixed the mysqld.sock :|

Comment: So, did that work, then?

Comment: To MySQL, yes. Thank you. Now I have to check the rest, some things might be broken too and I didn't notice...yet :|